# Set Run Configuration for Cucumber in Webstorm

Tags: cucumber, webstorm

Trying to run features files from WebStorm IDE

When trying to execute the feature files I get following message

I'm not able to set "Executable Path" so when I click on the green arrow I get following message
*"Cannot run program D:\example-protractor-master\node_modules-bin"*

Attaching the screenshot

[image]
http://screencast.com/t/oRaPpUUsuEy

Can anyone tell me how to set the configuration window for Cucumber?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

'Executable path' should be a full path to cucumber-js executable (`cucumber-js.cmd` on Windows), like `C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\cucumber-js.cmd`. Directory you have specified, indeed, can't be executed