# Running cucumber.js in WebStorm

Tags: angularjs, cucumber, protractor, bdd, webstorm

I need help trying to run a cucumber feature file from within WebStorm. I want to do this as WebStorm allows me to run scenarios, instead of running whole features.

I am running an Angular client, and want to carry out end-to-end testing so I am using Protractor and Cucumber.

There are various errors I am getting depending on what I try, but the main ones are:

- **Error running test.feature
  Cannot run program “usr/local/bin/cucumber.js” (in directory “My project's test directory”): error=2, No such file or directory**

This is the error I get when trying to run a feature/scenario in WebStorm.

- **ReferenceError: browser is not defined**

This is after I edit “Run Configurations” and pass in the path to the cucumber.js executable from ~/.nvm/versions/node/v5.10.1/bin/cucumber.js

and I have also tried passing in the cucumber.js exe that's located in the project, but I get the same error.

On the flip side, when I **cd** into my project root, and use protractor on the command line, after passing it my config.js file, it runs the feature file without a problem!

So as you can see, it seems to work on the command line using protractor, but with the number of feature files and scenarios I expect to have, it would be great to run scenarios individually.

For your information:

I can't remember how I installed NPM and Node, but the set up is as follows:

- NPM: version 3.8.3. The directory for NPM is ~/.nvm/versions/node/v5.10.1/bin/npm
- Node: version v5.10.1 ~/.nvm/versions/node/v5.10.1/bin/node
- NodeJS: v0.10.25 /usr/bin/nodejs

Cucumber – I installed this globally, but also local to the project.

Protractor Cucumber-framework – installed as a dev dependency: see package.json file for project.

Protractor – installed globally.

The structure of my project is as follows:

```
Project
. http
. node_modules
 .. cucumber
   ... bin
      .... cucumber.js
. src
. test
 .. step_definitions
   ... test_steps.js
 ..test.feature
. conf.js (for cucumber)
. karma.conf.js
. package.json
. webpack.config.js
```

**contents of conf.js file:**

```
exports.config = {

seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
framework: 'custom',

specs: [
    'test/features/test.feature'
],

capabilities: {
    'browserName' : 'chrome'
},

baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9000',
cucumberOpts : {
    require: 'test/features/step_definitions/test_steps.js',
    format: 'pretty'
},

frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework')
};
```

**project's package.json file contents:**

```
{
  "name": "test_draft",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -p --display-modules",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --content-base http/ --hot --inline",
    "test": "karma start"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.3",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.2.18",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "jquery": "^2.2.3",
    "pikaday": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "cucumber": "^0.10.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-mocha": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^0.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.15",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

I just want to be able to right click a scenario, and run it.

There are various discussions related to Cucumber and WebStorm, however none of these have helped.

Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Set Run Configuration for Cucumber in Webstorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32509809/set-run-configuration-for-cucumber-in-webstorm) and for the directory structure https://www.relishapp.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/docs/command-line-interface